# MIPS/QtSpim Register 1 is reserved for assembler error, a very simple program

Tags: mips, qtspim, spim

Error:

> spim: (parser) Register 1 is reserved for assembler on line 1 of file /Users/zhangchen/Desktop/1.asm
>         nor $1, $0,$0;    #$1=FFFF_FFFF

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRFJd.png)

```
nor $1, $0,$0;      #$1=FFFF_FFFF
sltu $2, $0, $1;    #$2=0000_0001
add $3, $2, $2;     #$3=0000_0002
add $4, $3, $2;     #$4=0000_0003
add $5, $4, $3;     #$5=0000_0005
add $6, $5, $3;     #$6=0000_0007
sllv $7, $6, $2;    #$7=0000_000E
add $9, $5, $6;     #$9=0000_000C
sllv $8, $6, $9;    #$8=0000_7000
xor $9, $1, $8;     #$9=FFFF_8FFF
add $10, $9, $1;    #$10=FFFF_8FFE
sub $11, $8, $7;    #$11=0000_6FF2
sub $12, $7, $8;    #$12=FFFF_900E
and $13, $9, $12;   #$13=FFFF_800E
or $14, $9, $12;    #$14=FFFF_9FFF
or $15, $6, $7;     #$15=0000_000F
nor $16, $6, $7;    #$16=FFFF_FFF0
add $17, $7, $3;    #$17=0000_0010
sllv  $18, $8, $17;     #$18=7000_0000
sllv  $19, $3, $17;     #$19=0002_0000
sllv $20, $19, $7;      #$20=8000_0000
add  $21, $20, $1;      #$21=7FFF_FFFF
or $22, $18, $21;       #$22=7FFF_FFFF
add  $23, $20, $22;     #$23=FFFF_FFFF
sub $24, $20, $22;      #$24=0000_0001
sub $25, $22, $20;      #$25=FFFF_FFFF
xor $26, $18, $1;       #$26=8FFF_FFFF
sltu $27, $22, $20;     #$27=0000_0001
sltu $28, $26, $20;     #$28=0000_0000
add $29, $22, $2;       #$29=8000_0000
sub $30, $20, $2;       #$30=7FFF_FFFF
add $31, $11, $26;      #$30=9000_6FF1
```

Comment: use `.set noat` if you want to use `$at`/`$1` for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The error means exactly what it says. Register `$1` is also know as `$at` (as in **A**ssembler **T**emporary), and may be used by the assembler e.g. to hold intermediate results in code generated from pseudo-instructions.

You should generally not use `$1` in your own code. It may be allowed by some assemblers, at least if you disable support for pseudo-instructions. Whether QtSPIM supports that, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

This code comes from a Chinese textbook, which points out that if you want to run this code normally, you need to set the Simulator mode to **bare machine** mode first, you can set this in Simulator-Settings.

By the way, this code has some errors(such as the value of #21 overflowed).

(Book's name is *Experimental Instructions on Computer Composition Principle and System Structure(Second Edition)*)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).